# When launching node on remote machine, is the local or remote version of the package used?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If PC 1 runs Node A on PC 2, does PC 2 use the code from PC 1 or PC2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257152/when-launching-node-on-remote-machine,-is-the-local-or-remote-version-of-the--package-used?/) by [hwil292](https://answers.ros.org/users/29711/hwil292/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What `roslaunch` really does is start a client `roslaunch` on PC 2 (using SSH), which is then used by the master `roslaunch` server on PC 1 to start nodes on PC 2, but those binaries will need to be present on PC 2 (they don't get up or downloaded by anyone in this setup).

So in your words: PC 2 will "use the code from PC 2".

See also [wiki/roslaunch/Architecture - Remote Processes](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Architecture#Remote_processes) for some details about how this works.

---

Edit: I've seen setups which worked around this limitation by using NFS (or a similar remote FS) to export a workspace that was then shared by all hosts. In this way all hosts would start the exact same nodes, but of course this comes with its own difficulties.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hwil292](https://answers.ros.org/users/29711/hwil292/) on 2017-03-16**:
I thought that was case, but always good to check. Thank you!